# python - Class instance's inconsistent behaviour

Tags: python-2.7, class, object, self

python class's instance is behaving inconsistently.

Code.1

```
    class A():
        def __init__(self, x):
            self.x = x
        def update(self, x):
            self.x = x

    a = A(3)
    a.update(5)
    print a.x # prints 5
```

Code.2

```
    class A():
        def __init__(self, x):
            self.x = x
        def update(self, x):
            self = A(x)

    a = A(3)
    a.update(5)
    print a.x # prints 3
```

Why is 'x' attribute getting updated in the first snippet and is not getting updated in 2nd one?

Comment: Cannot reproduce. This (correctly) prints `<module.A instance at 0x.......>` Are you sure that you are executing the code you are showing?

Comment: @dhke: sorry I made a mistake in 2nd code snippet, Please check now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assigning to `self` does not change the current object. It just assigns a new value to the (local) self parameter variable.

The only special treatment that the `self` gets is during invocation, in the sense that

```
a.update(x)
```

is equivalent to

```
A.update(a, x)
```

Assigning to `self` just overrides the value of the local parameter:

```
def update(self, x):
    # overwrite the value of self with a different instance of A
    # This has no effect outside of update().
    self = A(x)

a = A(3)
a.update(5)
```

In this case `a` is still the same instance from `A(3)`. You created a new instance of `A` inside `update()` and assigned it to the `self` parameter, but that modification does not carry over outside of `update()`.